# Why There is a Long List Waiting for Internet: What Does http Do?

Tags: internet, log

My internet connection has become so much slow.

I am using Chromium browser. In addition to it, Dropbox and Ubuntu One is connected.

But there is a long list in Nethogs.

[image]

Why is that ?

What does http doing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` is used by the package manager (APT) to download files, like `.deb` packages and package lists.

If you aren't installing new packages or updates it's quite likely the update manager updating its package lists.

Comment: How can I disable it temporarily ?. I used `sudo pkill update-manager`. But seems not working.